# Botium file upload error - "Excel registration failed - Value for field filecontent is too long"

Tags: automated-tests, chatbot

Trying to upload a test excel file of size 320 KB on Botium (Local CE edition) but Botium is returning `Excel registration failed - Value for field filecontent is too long.` error message.

Expected result - For the file to upload successfully

Actual Result - `Excel registration failed - Value for field filecontent is too long.` error message.

Screenshot of the error message - [link](https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/442/mNC1dT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Currently the maximum file size uploading Excel files is restricted by the database system backing Botium Box and Prisma (by default mysql). We have a story in our backlog to use an external storage for large Excel files. Currently, the only solution (and by the way, something we usually recommend to all of our Botium Box users) is to use a Git repository or at least a shared folder to place your Excel files.

[image]

*(with Botium Box Community Edition, Git option not available)*

You should do like this:

- Create a subdirectory in the resources-Folder and place the Excel file there
- Register this folder, but prefix it with /app/server/resources (instead of the physical path on your local workstation - this folder is mapped to the Docker environment)
- Now you can use this test set as usual

UPDATE:
To see the Test Set contents, use the "Compile Test Set and Update Statistics" button:

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the resources folder that was created automatically as part of botium installation? If yes, we created a new folder called TV and placed our test excel file there. As per your instructions, we registered this as a shared folder with path - /app/server/resources/TV and ran the test but botium hasn't picked the file up :(

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of your shared folder configuration screen. And what happens if you click the "Compile Test Set and Update Statistics" button ?